# Tags appear stretched in Chrome / Mobile (Android)

Tags: bug, tags, user-interface

I'm not sure if this is because of the latest Chrome app update, but for some time now I've noticed tags appear to stretch to random widths, in an inconsistent manner (sometimes they look fine).

Running Chrome 38.0.2125.102 on Android 4.4.2, here are a few screenshots:

[image: stretched tags]

Same goes for bounties:

[image: stretched bounty]

Comment: @200_success hmm just noticed it on [SO] as well.

Comment: First thing coming to mind is userscript/browser extension, e.g. the [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch). If you have any of those, disable/remove them and see if it helps. If so, it is out of SE hands.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Quite sure Chrome mobile, unlike its desktop cousin, can't run extensions or userscripts, so that can't be the issue

Comment: The same on my phone running same versions of chrome and android